# iOS 9 - Location background updates only happening on second push to background

Tags: background, cllocationmanager, ios9

In iOS9, when the app goes into the background (all appropriate flags et al for background processing are set, including the new allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates property), the location manager reports updates for 10 seconds then sleeps.  After bringing the app back to the foreground and thence to the background again, the updates work continuously as expected.

This is only happening in iOS9 (non-beta) not in iOS7 or iOS8.

Has anyone else come across this behaviour?

Comment: I noticed the same. Only setting `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false` seemed to solve it. Unfortunately this comes with a battery usage penalty

Comment: Thanks for responding; this flag is set to false already and the issue still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting, allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates, is documented as being able to control the runtime settings for background processing; however, the flag **cannot** be set in:

```
applicationDidEnterBackground:
```

If the flag failed consistently because it is not possible to utilise in this method; then it would have been easier to track down but it failed only on the first entry to the background.

This entails that there is an issue with the flag being reset in:

```
applicationWillEnterForeground:
```

The upshot is that the flag cannot be set in the method life cycles; therefore, the flag is generally set on initialisation of the app which entails that the flag, as it stands, is not particularly useful.